# Quick Question About NSFetchRequest and Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my Core Data model, I have an entity Session and Exercise.

Session has a to many relationship to Exercise (there is a one-one inverse relationship as well).

In my fetch, I am trying to find all Session object that are related to the current Exercise.

I am using the following code which isn't working.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"exercise = %@", exercise.name]];
NSEntityDescription *sessionEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:sessionEntity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);
self.sessionArray = results;
```

Here is my data model:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from the screenshot it seems that your relationship attribute of the Session entity is called `exercises` not `exercise`.

Also, it seems to me that it would work if you searched not the Session entity but the Exercise entity and then iterate through the resulting array to extract the sessions.

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"name == %@", exerciseName]];
NSEntityDescription *exerciseEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:exerciseEntity];
...    
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
...
NSMutableArray *mutableSessionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Exercise *ex in results) {
    Session *session = [ex exercises];
    if (session) [mutableSessionArray addObject:session];
}
self.sessionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableSessionArray];
```

The relationship of the Exercise entity called `exercises` could be called `session` for clarity. I would recommend renaming it.

BTW, you can also write `=` instead of `==`, they are equivalent, as far as I know. In the [Predicate Programming Guide section on Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB) it says:

> ```
> =, ==
> The left-hand expression is equal to the right-hand expression.
> ```

Comment: Thanks Mundi, but I am trying to get an array filled with all the sessions for which there exists an exercise with the name I have for exercise.name.

Comment: @Faisal, exactly. That's how I would do it. Each of your resulting exercises has exactly 1 Session associated with it.

Comment: Yes, but how can I get an array of Sessions out of this?  I understand that `Session *session = exerciseVariable.exercises;` will give me one Session?

Comment: @Faisal: I will write the code into the answer for easier formatting.

Comment: I think your missing `[fetchRequest setEntity:sessionEntity];`

Comment: At line `[mutableSessionArray addObject:session];`, I'm getting error : `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0`

Comment: Looks like you have exercises not associated with any sessions. I edited my answer to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your predicate you use =, == is the comparison operator. I think that's where you're going wrong.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html